# Another method of implementing '0' list in Python

Tags: python

This is the only method I know of making a list of the same size with zeros. Just curious, is there another way?

```
line = [13,20,0,44]
result = []

for i in range(len(line)):
    result.append(0)
print (result)
```

Comment: and then there is the `result = [0 for _ in line]` method. But why do you want to do that? You do not have to initialize `list`s in Python

Comment: [0] * len(line)

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2 & 3**

```
out = [0 for _ in line]
-- OR --
out = [0] * len(line)
```

Comment: This is Python 2 only.

Comment: Why not just `[0] * len(line)`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, fixed

Comment: @vaultah, thanks, added!

Comment: @vaultah Agreed, in this case that is shorter, but this pattern has some perils like in `[X()] * 10` where `X` is a mutable type, when all list elements will reference the same object unlike using the first idiom `[X() for _ in range(...)]`

Comment: If you like it more cryptic: `map(lambda _:0, line)`

Comment: @vaultah True, I still think it's noteworthy for beginners that the two patterns are not equivalent.